# Combine two string arrays into a matrix

Tags: arrays, string, matlab

This should be simple but is unbelievably hard and frustrating in Matlab.  If I have a string array like this

```
row = ['A','a']
```

and another like this

```
column = ['a','a']
```

How would I get

```
    matrix ='A'   'a'
      'a' [ 'Aa'  'aa'     
      'a'  'aA'   'aa'  ]
```

I've tried Kronecker tensor which doesn't work on strings, I have to do all sorts of obnoxious cell and string conversions and Matlab has this annoying behavior of converting string arrays to regular strings messing up my values and spacing.

Comment: Will each string always be exactly 1 character, or do strings otherwise always have equal length? And is your problem always 2x2 or can it be big as well, and if so, what is the pattern?

Comment: Instead of posting a very frustrated and opinionated question, please describe exactly what you want to accomplish (because it looks like you're just using the wrong syntax for your purposes). It's not clear what you want to accomplish, so it's hard for us to give you a good answer.

Comment: @DennisJaheruddin - Each allele/string will always be one character.

Comment: @RodyOldenhuis How is this an opinionated question? Im trying to efficiently generate a table combination of strings...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looking for [**`strcat()`**](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/strcat.html), which will concatenate strings horizontally:

```
row = {'A' 'a'};
result1 = strcat(row, 'a');
result2 = strcat('a', row);
```

After this, you will get:

```
result1 = 

    'Aa'    'aa'


result2 = 

    'aA'    'aa'
```

Comment: To questions..
1. What is it called when you use curly braces instead of brackets with no commas - is that a set?
2. Would I be able to do this all at one time programmatically(vectorize) if I wanted to generate a(much) bigger table

Comment: @Leon 1. It's called `cell array`. 2. Sure, as long as you follow the rule of cell array to create bigger ones.

Answer (score 1):

This will work:

```
row = ['A','a']

col = ['a'; 'a']

M = {[row(1), col(1)], [row(1), col(2)]; 
     [row(2), col(1)], [row(2), col(2)]}
```

And it's very simple to generalize to a loop if you have longer "index" vectors.

```
for r = 1:size(row,2)
    for c = 1:size(col,1)
            M{r,c} = [row(r), col(c)];
    end;
end;
```

Notice that I have used curly brackets instead of square, this makes it use a **cell array** instead of a normal array which is how you would get the "spacing" you require.

Comment: Thank you for the answer Dan.  Is there a more programmatic way of creating this?  Such as some built in matlab functions?

Comment: @Leon Yes... use a loop.